# What do the triangles in the Ghost in the Shell (2017) poster symbolize?

Tags: analysis, posters, ghost-in-the-shell-2017

This poster has two triangles, one is superimposed on Scarlett Johansson.

The second triangle in the logo.

What are the artists trying to show with these symbols?

[image: poster from ghost in the shell]

Comment: It's edgy, get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for the same last week after watching the movie when I found this on Reddit. This looks like the correct explanation and makes sense.

> The triangle represents three components of the human psyche; Id, Ego,
>   and Super Ego.

Here is the source Reddit discussion [page](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ghost_in_the_Shell/comments/64ekox/significance_of_the_deltatriangle_in_title/?st=j59dtzff&sh=7961c6ac).